# Spring-Boot autoconfigure

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hello Team i have a error to init a Spring-Boot aplication because i change the parent version of spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.3.Release to 2.2.4.RELEASE because im doing a changes with azure appConfiguration but when i trying to execture it im reciving the nex error.

```
ERROR 14244 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
```

and my rest POM is this.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>action-book-rest</artifactId>
    <name>Action Book (Rest)</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.biit</groupId>
        <artifactId>action-book</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/..</main.basedir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.biit</groupId>
            <artifactId>action-book-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-azure-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-feature-management-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Telemetry -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${org.testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- if this is not excluded and 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2' enabled, 
                testng causes a 'Cannot instantiate class' for all tests -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.subethamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>subethasmtp-wiser</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.biit</groupId>
            <artifactId>action-underlying-model</artifactId>
            <version>${action-underlying-model.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.biit</groupId>
            <artifactId>openproject-database-structure</artifactId>
            <version>${openproject-database-structure.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${tinkerpop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.biit</groupId>
            <artifactId>open-project-structure</artifactId>
            <version>${open-project-structure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Do not deploy this module in artifact -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know what my mistake is, or what to try.

Comment: This normally shows it self as there are 1.x spring boot autoconfigurations packaged in. Running `mvn dependency:tree` will highlight them. The only fix is to use the correct versions of the autoconfigurations for your spring boot version

Comment: this is my dependency tree but i´m not see any conflict with the versions

Answer (score 0):

Try obtaining the list with all dependencies and see if there is any conflict between them:
mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the issue is on the stacktrace of the error that you are not showing. Probably some chained exception that prevents the propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to be created. A missing property or a needed bean that also fails. Take a look on it or post the complete stacktrace to be possible for us to dig into it.